# Page Curl harism - Using button on layouts

Tags: android, curl

I am using the page curl harism lib to implement page curl in my app. You can find the lib [here](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/).
 I have managed to put layouts instead of images on the pages. But the layout is not clickable. The buttons in the layout cannot be clicked. How do make them clickable?

Activity code:

```
package com.Test.pagecurldemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class CurlActivity extends Activity {

private CurlView mCurlView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    int index = 0;
    if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
        index = (Integer) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    }
    mCurlView = (CurlView) findViewById(R.id.curl);
    mCurlView.setPageProvider(new PageProvider());
    mCurlView.setSizeChangedObserver(new SizeChangedObserver());
    mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(3);
    mCurlView.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);

    // This is something somewhat experimental. Before uncommenting next
    // line, please see method comments in CurlView.
    // mCurlView.setEnableTouchPressure(true);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCurlView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCurlView.onResume();
}

@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return mCurlView.getCurrentIndex();
}

/**
 * Bitmap provider.
 */
private class PageProvider implements CurlView.PageProvider {

    // Bitmap resources.
    private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.layout.gold, R.layout.bismuth, R.layout.zinc, R.layout.beryllium, R.layout.helium};

    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = inflater.inflate(mBitmapIds[index],null);
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePage(CurlPage page, int width, int height, int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0: {
            Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 0);
            page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
            page.setColor(Color.rgb(49, 79, 79), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 1);
            page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
            page.setColor(Color.rgb(49, 79, 79), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 2);
            page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
            page.setColor(Color.rgb(49, 79, 79), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 3);
            page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
            page.setColor(Color.rgb(49, 79, 79), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            Bitmap front = loadBitmap(width, height, 4);
            page.setTexture(front, CurlPage.SIDE_FRONT);
            page.setColor(Color.rgb(49, 79, 79), CurlPage.SIDE_BACK);
            break;
        }
        }
    }

}
/**
 * CurlView size changed observer.
 */
private class SizeChangedObserver implements CurlView.SizeChangedObserver {
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h) {
        if (w > h) {
            mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
            mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .05f, .1f, .05f);
        } else {
            mCurlView.setViewMode(CurlView.SHOW_ONE_PAGE);
            mCurlView.setMargins(.1f, .1f, .1f, .1f);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Please guide me as I am not an expert in android. I know this question has been asked here but it didn't have an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by layout is not clickable...

Comment: I mean that i can only turn the page by touching the layout. I cannot click any button in it.

Comment: Can you post your activity code also.

Comment: yes. please check my edit for the activity code.

Comment: Wait for sometime i will try your as well as i too have some code for this. and will update you after sometime.

Comment: @InnocentKiller please acknowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not clickable because pages are just bitmaps.When you add layout or buttons bitmaps will be drawn

Comment: then how to add click listners

Comment: Again, even if you put some layout there, they will be transported to bitmaps. However, by intercepting touch events you can prevent curling pages and set tap listener( which will work like click listener) by implementing gesture detectors

Comment: can i use an edittext in layout and add curl effect to it. can user type some text on it???